# Convert Pandas dataframe to an api format

Tags: python, pandas

I the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2023, 2024, 2022,2022, 2023,2025,2024,2025,2022,2023],'Name': ['John', 'Jim', 'John','Jim', 'John','Jim','John','Jim','John','Jim']
                  ,'Month': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb','Jan', 'Jan','Feb','Jan','Jan','Feb','Feb'],'Day': [1, 2, 5,6, 7,4,8,24,13,15]})
df
```

which looks like:

[image]

I am trying to convert this to a dictionary/api format so it can be use in a `get` request.

I need it in a format that is grouped by `Name`, then `Year`, then `Month` and the values are `Day`. My front end output expected is this

[image]

By any help to create the dictionary/api view to achieve this would be fantastic. Thanks very much

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problem you have?

Comment: I don't know how to convert so i was hoping someone could help point me in the right direction with a solution

Comment: You can use [DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [DataFrame.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) or [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632)